# "Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces defines some interfaces that will use a DHCP client or static address"

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, dhcpcd

Deployment:

```
VM -- (eth0)RPI(wlan0) -- Router -- ISP
 ^      ^         ^         ^ 
DHCP  Static     DHCP      GW
```

NOTE: RPI hostname: `gateway`

• The goal was to make VMs accessible from the outside the network. Accomplished, according to the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IAa4tI4JrgI, via the Port Forwarding on Router and RPI, by installing dhcpcd and configuring iptables on RPI.

• Here is my `interfaces`, where I have commented out the auto wlan0, in attempt to fix the issue (before, it was uncommented, and was still the same thing...)

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

#auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid FunBox-84A8
wpa-psk 7A73FA25C43563523D7ED99A4D

#auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.2.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

• Here is the `firewall.conf` used by the `iptables`:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [86:11520]
:INPUT ACCEPT [64:8940]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [71:5638]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [37:4255]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.21/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 170 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.83:22
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.21/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 171 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.83:443
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.21/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.66:3389
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3188:209284]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [25:2740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2306:270630]
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [55445:38248798]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3188:209284]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [52257:38039514]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2306:270630]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [54565:38310208]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [55445:38248798]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2306:270630]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Feb 17 20:01:56 2019
```

• `iptables -L`:

```
pi@gateway:/etc$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

• Here is the `dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
# Some non-RFC compliant DHCP servers do not reply with this set.
# In this case, comment out duid and enable clientid above.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# Example static IP configuration:
#interface eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
#static ip6_address=fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::ff/64
#static routers=192.168.0.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8 fd51:42f8:caae:d92e::1

# It is possible to fall back to a static IP if DHCP fails:
# define static profile
#profile static_eth0
#static ip_address=192.168.1.23/24
#static routers=192.168.1.1
#static domain_name_servers=192.168.1.1

# fallback to static profile on eth0
#interface eth0
#fallback static_eth0

denyinterfaces eth0

host Accountant {
hardware ethernet 10:60:4b:68:03:21;
fixed-address 192.168.2.83;
}

host Accountant1 {
hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:35:95:ed;
fixed-address 192.168.2.66;
}
host Accountant3 {
hardware ethernet 30:85:A9:1B:C4:8B;
fixed-address 192.168.2.70;
}
```

• The error message, that I am not able to figure out:

```
root@gateway:/home/pi# systemctl restart dhcpcd
Warning: dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Job for dhcpcd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status dhcpcd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@gateway:/home/pi# systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-02-17 20:36:42 GMT; 6s ago
  Process: 775 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=6)

Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: DHCP client or static address
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=6
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Warning: dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
root@gateway:/home/pi#               
root@gateway:/home/pi# systemctl daemon-reload
root@gateway:/home/pi# systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2019-02-17 20:36:42 GMT; 1min 23s ago

Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway dhcpcd[775]: DHCP client or static address
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=6
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 17 20:36:42 gateway systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
root@gateway:/home/pi#
```

•`gateway` version:

```
pi@gateway:/etc$ cat os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Questions:

1) What does the error message `Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces defines some interfaces that will use a DHCP client or static address` mean? How to fix it, according to my config above?

2) Why hosts are not getting assigned the IP address according to my dhcpcd.conf, except the host `Accountant`, which is always getting the same IP, which I want, even if comment out the binding...? How to fix it, in order to be able to bind more than one hosts MAC with IP?

3) What does this notation mean:

```
#auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.2.0
        broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

What are the notation rules for the `interfaces` file in Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1.) Sorry, it looks like you've misunderstood a few things.

`dhcpcd` is a DHCP **client** daemon, which is normally started by NetworkManager or `ifupdown`, not directly by `systemd`. It is what will be handling the IP address assignment for your `wlan0`.

You *can* use `dhcpcd` as started by `systemd` if you wish, however that will require disabling all the normal network interface configuration logic (i.e. `/etc/network/interfaces` must be empty of non-comment lines) of the distribution and replacing it with your own custom scripting wherever necessary. That is for special uses only; if you're not absolutely certain you should do that, you shouldn't.

`dhcpcd` will never serve IP addresses to any other hosts. This part you added to `dhcpcd.conf` looks like it would belong to the configuration file of ISC DHCP **server** daemon, `dhcpd` (yes it's just one-letter difference) instead:

```
host Accountant {
hardware ethernet 10:60:4b:68:03:21;
fixed-address 192.168.2.83;
}

host Accountant1 {
hardware ethernet 00:0c:29:35:95:ed;
fixed-address 192.168.2.66;
}
host Accountant3 {
hardware ethernet 30:85:A9:1B:C4:8B;
fixed-address 192.168.2.70;
}
```

But if you are following the YouTube tutorial you mentioned, you might not even have `dhcpd` installed, since `dnsmasq` is supposed to do that job.

As far as I can tell, the equivalent syntax for `dnsmasq.conf` would be:

```
dhcp-host=10:60:4b:68:03:21,192.168.2.83,Accountant
dhcp-host=00:0c:29:35:95:ed,192.168.2.66,Accountant1
dhcp-host=30:85:A9:1B:C4:8B,192.168.2.70,Accountant3
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually used `dnsmasq`, so this is based on just quickly Googling its man page.

---

Question 2.) In the tutorial you mentioned, `dnsmasq` was supposed to act as a DHCP server on `eth0`. You did not say anything about it, so I don't know whether it was running or not. If not, the one client that was always getting the same IP might have been simply falling back to a previously-received old DHCP lease that wasn't expired yet. Yes, DHCP clients may store a DHCP lease persistently and keep using it if a network doesn't seem to have a working DHCP server available.

---

Question 3.): `/etc/network/interfaces` is a classic Debian/Ubuntu style network interface configuration file. Use `man interfaces` to see documentation for it, or [look here.](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html)

In Debian, *Ubuntu, Raspbian etc., NetworkManager will have a plug-in that will *read* `/etc/network/interfaces` but won't *write* to it.

If NetworkManager configuration tools like `nmcli`, `nmtui` or GUI-based NetworkManager configuration tools of your desktop environment of choice are used, the configuration would be saved to files in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory instead.

If NetworkManager is not installed, the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is used by the `ifupdown` package, which includes the commands `ifup` and `ifdown`. The package also includes a system start-up script that will run `ifup -a` on boot, enabling all network interfaces that have `auto <interface name>` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. There is also an udev rule which will run `ifup <interface name>` if a driver for a new network interface gets auto-loaded and `/etc/network/interfaces` has an `allow-hotplug <interface name>` line for it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, very helpful! It looks like dnsmasq running:`pi@gateway:~$ systemctl status dnsmasq
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-02-18 08:59:49 GMT; 4h 53min ago
 Main PID: 639 (dnsmasq)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
           └─639 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` I have just understood, that it is `A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server`

Comment: So, in this case, I can even uninstall `dhcpcd`, as it seems doing nothing, since `dnsmasq` is doing everything??

Comment: And, regarding the error message, first Q, do you mean, that I should invoke the dhcpcd in other way than using `systemctl start dhcpcd`, right?

Comment: I mean that if you're using `/etc/network/interfaces`, then either `NetworkManager` will run `dhcpcd` for you on `wlan0`, or you could run `ifup wlan0` which will also run `dhcpcd` for you. If you uncomment `auto wlan0` in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the automatic `ifup -a` executed by boot scripts will do it; if you add `allow-hotplug wlan0`, then the udev rules will invoke `ifup wlan0` as soon as the driver for it is loaded.

Comment: The point is, that, it looks like NetworkManager is not running, at least:   `pi@gateway:/etc/init.d$ /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
-bash: /etc/init.d/network-manager: No such file or directory
pi@gateway:/etc/init.d$ /etc/init.d/network-manager status
-bash: /etc/init.d/network-manager: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay, then forget anything I said about NetworkManager. Then the `ifup` and `ifdown` commands and the related boot scripts and udev rules of the `ifupdown` package will be in effect.

Comment: That's OK. `loaded` just means that `systemd` has the service definition from `/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service`. Raspbian has a default configuration that is different from standard Debian and uses `dhcpcd.conf` and `wpasupplicant.conf` for basic network configuration [(see here)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39785/93995) and recommends keeping `/etc/network/interfaces` unchanged, although the change seems not be documented too well. But last time I checked, using `/etc/network/interfaces` Debian-style still worked too.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason for this "error".

`dhcpcd` uses some kind of "noob/newbie protection", which guarantees a safe way for handling the network management, should some "noob/newbie" try to use both `dhcpcd` and `/etc/interfaces`.

`dhcpcd` checks the `/etc/interfaces` with the following shell-script `/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

DHCPCD=/sbin/dhcpcd
INTERFACES=/etc/network/interfaces

if grep -q -E "^[[:space:]]*iface[[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]*inet[[:space:]]*(dhcp|static)" \
                $INTERFACES; then
        echo "Not running dhcpcd because $INTERFACES"
        echo "defines some interfaces that will use a"
        echo "DHCP client or static address"
        exit 6
fi

exec $DHCPCD $@
```

I simply alternated the line

`if grep -q -E "^[[:space:]]*iface[[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]*inet[[:space:]]*(dhcp|static)" \`

by removing the `|static` argument, to

`if grep -q -E "^[[:space:]]*iface[[:space:]]*.*[[:space:]]*inet[[:space:]]*(dhcp)" \`

and adjusted the last echo line to:

`echo "DHCP client"`

**PS** make sure to add a `denyinterfaces "NAME OF YOUR STATIC INTERFACE, WHICH SHALL BE CONTROLLED ONLY BY /etc/interfaces"`, for example `denyinterfaces eth0` to your `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Comment: I have hit this issue with the latest version of the raspberry pi.  There is a simpler solution.  You need to ensure your static configuration goes in /etc/network/interfaces.d/ folder rather than the /etc/network/interfaces file itself.

For some reason, dhcpcd disables itself if it finds a declaration in /etc/network/interfaces but it is fine if you declare it within the folder /etc/network/interfaces.d/

Comment: This was it! What worked in previous Raspian versions doesn't anymore: Adding content to /etc/interfaces. Moving it to /etc/interfaces.d/somenamenodots. And denyinterfaces in /etc/dhcpcd.conf was also very helpful!